# Whats wrong here? Why red under line appear to the code?

Tags: android

The project build and run without any error but those red line appearing.

[image]

Comment: Just copy the text into a code block rather than giving us an image.

Comment: If you hover over your code, Android Studio will tell you what's wrong. And if you click that red bulb, it'll suggest solutions

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, Check your gradle for constraintlayout, it should be in your dependencies but if it's not add the following line

```
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
```

P.S I'm not using the latest version.